# WordPress: Allowed Memory Size Exhausted - After Moving from Dev to Live

Tags: theme-development, memory

I keep getting this on my WordPress site after I moved it from my development server to the live site. It's happening in one file that is using a few functions which I think is causing it, but I don't know how to fix it.

> Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 452314848 bytes) in **Unknown** on line **0**

The code of the file that is causing the problem is here: [custom.php](http://pastebin.com/gBR29w5G)

I think it is one of these functions: `ob_flush()` or `ob_end_flush()`.

How this started happening:

I finished development of the site using WordPress MU (only 2 blogs in the network), originally I had it working with sub-directories. Once I moved it to the live server, I switched to sub-domains and got them working fine (both sites are showing) but I am getting that error in `custom.php`, causing some JavaScript to stop functioning.

By the way, this **only happens about 85% of the time**, not every time the error shows.

Let me add that I am customizing a theme called [Repro](http://themeforest.net/item/repro-premium-wordpress-news-magazine-theme/138755), if it is of any relevance. Anyways, if anyone can help me troubleshoot on why this is happening, and what I can do to fix it, I would be very grateful, thanks!

**Things I have tried:**

Increasing the memory limit using `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');` in `wp-config.php`. - No luck

Switching themes - The problem only persists on the Repro theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, this is an issue specific to the Theme. You should consult the developer and/or ThemeForest for Theme-specific solutions. As this is a commercial Theme, we have no way of seeing the Theme files, or of helping to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to a different theme to see if the problem still persists. If it doesn't, activate your theme again. That's worked for me before, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: Just tried this, it does not show the error on TwentyEleven, but when I switch back to the theme that I need to use, the problem comes back.